# How to Select the Token and Index from a Comma Separated String in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

Given a comma delimited string "a,b,c" I would like to split the string and select the token and its respective index into a list.

In other words, I want `"a,b,c".Split(',')` to return a list of:

```
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
```

I attempted the solution myself, but this is as close as I get. Of course, I only use `a.Index()` in the final line to indicate what I am trying to do.

```
public class var
{
    public string Token;
    public int Index;
}

List<var> varList = "a,b,c"
                       .Split(',')
                       .Select(a => new var { Token = a, Index = a.Index() };
```

Comment: Looks like there should be multi-author answers (currently there are 2 from 2 identical answers). I'd also like to see which of the answers will be marked as more correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the other overload of `Select`, [`.Select(Func<string, int, TResult>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) which gives us the index of the value.

```
List<Var> varList = "a,b,c".Split(',')
    .Select((a, i) => new Var { Token = a, Index = i + 1 })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload of [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) which provides indexing:

```
var list = "a,b,c".Split(',').Select((a,i) => new { Token = a, Index = i+1 }).ToList();
```

On a side note - I would recommend not using `var` as a class name, as it will conflict with the [C# `var` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).